# CiviMail not removing duplicate emails

Tags: civimail, duplicate-contacts

Using Joomla 3.6.2 and CiviCRM 4.7.11 and experiencing duplicate emails in CiviMail. We've tested with contacts with same email address + in same group, resulting in 2 emails received. We've also tested with contacts with same email address though in separate groups, resulting in 2 emails received. Attached image demonstrates 2 separate groups, each with 2 contacts in each group (different first/last names, though same email addresses... so 2 unique email addresses).

[image]

CiviMail component settings includes "CiviMail dedupes email addresses by default" as checked.

Edit: Connections

Also just tried to use the connections to provide a site profile assuming that might help troubleshoot this. Noticed in the image that the site url contains "administrator" twice. Perhaps this is a separate issue or maybe it's related?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has a related bug report: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19353. You may have to wait until it gets merged and released or you start to test with the proposed PRs.
Connections seems to be unrelated to this.